# how to modify element in a heap that contain a class

Tags: c++

```
class test{
public:
    test(){};
    void changeJ(int a) {j += a;}
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
};



struct comparator {
 bool operator()(test a, test b) {
 return a.i > b.i;
 }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    priority_queue<test, std::vector<test>, comparator> heap;
    test a;
    heap.push(a);
    heap.top().changeJ(1);
    return 0;
}
```

the priority queue is sorted by i, and i need to modify j,however,
The error I'm getting is in this line:

```
heap.top().changeJ(1);
error:assignmentiof member test::j n read-only object
```

how do i fix it?

Comment: `std::priority_queue::top()` returns a `const reference` to the top item in the container, so you cannot modify it this way

Comment: May want to move your initialization of i and j into a constructor.